# List of tables in all databases used in stored procedures

Tags: sql

We have created stored procedures which include lot of tables from different databases in same server. Now i need to list all the table corresponding  particular stored procedures.
I have tried the following query, but it shows only tables which related to particular database only.

**The query is attached here:**

```
SELECT
  t.TABLE_NAME,
  s.ROUTINE_NAME,
  s.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES s
  ON s.ROUTINE_NAME IN (SELECT
    referencing_entity_name
  FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME, 'OBJECT'))
  AND s.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND s.ROUTINE_NAME LIKE '%Procedure name%'
ORDER BY s.ROUTINE_NAME
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT t.TABLE_NAME, s.ROUTINE_NAME,s.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES s 
ON s.ROUTINE_NAME IN 
(
        SELECT referencing_entity_name 
        FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME, 'OBJECT')
)
AND s.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND s.ROUTINE_NAME LIKe '%Procedure name%'
ORDER BY s.ROUTINE_NAME

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specifics used.)

Answer (score 0):

This query will give a list of tables used in 'spName' Stored Procedure. You can also remove this condition to get details about all Stored procedures in the DB

```
SELECT TBL.TABLE_NAME, SR.ROUTINE_NAME,SR.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES TBL
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES SR 
    ON SR.ROUTINE_NAME IN 
    (
            SELECT referencing_entity_name 
            FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME, 'OBJECT')
    )
    AND SR.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
    WHERE TBL.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and SR.ROUTINE_NAME='spName'
```

Also
To obtain whole Tables List in DB use

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

And to obtain all Procedures name use

```
SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

Comment: i have tried this but it shows only the tables belongs to the database which we created the sp ,but i included the tables from different db's it does shows all the tables